# MySQL transpose table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a mysql table with the following structure:

```
|user_id|action_type|action_value|timestamp |
|-------|-----------|------------|----------|
|123    |click      |search      |20-07-2016|
|231    |click      |search      |20-07-2016|
|123    |click      |delete      |20-07-2016|
```

The thing is, action_type can take multiple values. They could be table columns but are dynamic so I decided to put them as values inside a column. Action_value is the value that can take an action_type. This is action per user/per date and I was wondering if it is possible to make a query that returns the following:

```
|action_type|timestamp |search|delete|
|-----------|----------|------|------|
|click      |20-07-2016|2     |1     |
|-----------|----------|------|------|
```

For a given action_type, return all the users that perform that action and group it by timestamp.

I tried the following query, but I'm just getting the same number in both columns:

```
SELECT T1.action_type, DATE(T1.timestamp), count(T1.action_value) 'search', count(T2.action_value) 'delete' FROM cohort_actions T1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT timestamp, action_value FROM cohort_actions WHERE action_value = 'delete' ) T2 ON DATE(T1.timestamp) = DATE(T2.timestamp) WHERE T1.action_type = 'click' AND T1.action_value = 'search' GROUP BY DATE(T1.timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to count only a subset of the rows, use an expression that is NULL when you don't want to count. COUNT() ignores NULLs.

```
SELECT action_type, DATE(timestamp) AS `timestamp`, 
  COUNT(CASE action_type WHEN 'click' THEN action_value END) AS `search`,
  COUNT(CASE action_type WHEN 'delete' THEN action_value END) AS `delete`,
FROM cohort_actions
GROUP BY action_type, DATE(timestamp);
```

Since I don't have an ELSE clause for those CASE expressions, the result of the expression is NULL unless the action_type is the desired value.